# get screenshot from clipboard in electron js as arrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Guys i need to get screenshot destop in electron js. Here is some libs to get screenshot,
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-screenshot-app],
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-desktop], also I tryed native api electron js [https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer] (this native api making only screen of electron app)

they are works fine but they make screenshot themself, when i call method screenshot (and returned as arrayBuffer), in my case i need to get screenshot(as arrayBuffer) from clipboard when clipboard has screenshot, that is if user clicked key PrtSc ...

if any hint or example please share ...

Comment: Assuming the image is in the clipboard, you can use [electrons clipboard API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/clipboard#clipboardreadimagetype) to get the image - Note however there is no way to distinguish between screenshots and other images

Comment: your advice helped me. Thanks
i solved so : 
`const buffer =  clipboard.readImage('clipboard').toPNG();`
and saved buffer as image with fs